# If and else statements don't work if my number variable is over certain value

Tags: c

When I input a value over 18.5 it state normal but anything under works. How do I set up the If and Else statements?

I am a student for a online course in C, and I have to do a program that calculates someone's BMI and display if they are "Normal", "Overweight", etc.

```
//Clear the screen
system("clear");

//Declare variables
float weight, height, bmi;
int number_of_inputs = 2;   //Interger constant or literal

//Get grades from user
printf("Please enter Weight in Pounds: ");
scanf("%f", &weight);

printf("Please enter your Height in inches: "); 
scanf("%f", &height);

//Calculate the BMI

bmi = 703 * (weight / (height * height) );

//Display what is the health status of the user

if (bmi >= 18.5 <= 24)
{
    printf("Your Health Status is Normal \n");
}

else if (bmi <= 18.5 >= 0)
{
    printf("Your Health Status is Underweight \n");
}

else if (bmi >= 25 <= 29)
{
    printf("Your Health Status is Overweight \n");
}

else if (bmi >= 30 <= 999)
{
    printf("Your Health Status is Obese \n");
}

printf("BMI: %f \n", bmi);

return (0);
```

Any value over 18.5 won't print the correct If/Else statement but anything under will

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing,  post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.   The posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files you actually used?

Comment: for `if (bmi >= 18.5 <= 24)` my compiler tells me "warning: comparison of constant ‘24’ with boolean expression is always true". There are similar warnings for the rest of your comparisons in that format.

Comment: OT: when writing a 'float' value, it must include a decimal point and a trailing 'f'.  Without the decimal point nor trailing `f` it is a `int` value.   With a decimal point but no trailing `f` it is a `double`

Comment: OT: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to enable the warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression like:

```
bmi >= 18.5 <= 24
```

does *not* do what you think it does. It should be written as:

```
bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24
```

---

In more detail, the erroneous expression is treated something like<sup>(1)</sup>:

```
(bmi >= 18.5) <= 24
```

where `bmi >= 18.5` gives you a `true/false` value represented as `1/0`. This `1` or `0` is then used to compare against `24`, which is why you seem to be getting bizarre results.

---

In fact, you don't really *need* to check both ends of the range since the possibilities cover the entire set of input values. I would suggest something like (with common stuff factored out):

```
printf("Your health status is ");
if      (bmi <= 18.5) puts("underweight");  // [-inf, 18.5]
else if (bmi <= 24.0) puts("normal");       // (18.5, 24.0]
else                  puts("overweight");   // (24.0, +inf]
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> I say "something like" since it depends on the evaluation order which I couldn't be bothered looking up at the moment. Firstly, it just decides *which* of the possible bizarre behaviours you'll see and, secondly, you don't need to worry about it if you just use the correct expression :-)

Comment: Oh, this helps me understand it better. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Condition like below:

```
if (bmi >= 18.5 <= 24)
```

should  be

```
if ((bmi >= 18.5) && (bmi <= 24))
```

Please check through-out your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem at here is that your if condition

```
if (bmi >= 18.5 <= 24)
```

in this condition, we can divide it like ((bmi >= 18.5) <= 24), assume: A = (bmi >= 18.5), this equation will get the value is 1 or 0 (true or false) and it will make the condition (A <= 24) always true. Therefore, in your program, it always go into the first if condition.
To resolve this problem, your program should be written as follows:

```
if((bmi >= 18.5) && (bmi <= 24)) {
    printf("Your Health Status is Normal \n");
} else {
// Continue write your code in here...
}
```